# How do I transpose a Dataframe and how to scatter plot the transposed df

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, scatter-plot, transpose

I have this dataframe with 20 countries and 20 years of data

```
Country 2000 2001 2002 ...
USA      1    2    3    
CANADA   4    5    6    
SWEDEN   7    8    9    
...
```

and I want to get a new df to create a scatter plot with y = value for each column (country) and x= Year

```
Country USA CANADA SWEDEN ...
2000     1    4    7    
2001     2    5    8    
2002     3    6    9    
...
```

My Code :

```
data = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
data.set_index("Country Name", inplace = True)
```

[image]

```
data_transposed = data.T
```

[image]

I'm struggling to create this kind of scatter plot.
Any idea ?
Thanks

Comment: Scatter plot is a 1x1 plot. Pick up any 2 columns and try `df.plot.scatter(x,y)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scatter is a plot which receives x and y only, you can scatter the whole dataframe directly. However, a small workaround:

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(data={"Country":["USA", "Canada", "Brasil"], 2000:[1,4,7], 2001:[3,7,9], 2002: [2,8,5]})

for column in df.columns:
    if column != "Country":
        plt.scatter(x=df["Country"], y=df[column])
plt.show()
```

result:

[image: result fig]

It just plotting each column separately, eventually you get what you want.
As you see, each year is represent by different colors - you can do the opposite (plotting years and having countries as different colors). Scatter is 1x1: you have Country, Year, Value. You can present only two of them in a scatter plot (unless you use colors for example)

You need to transpose your dataframe for that (as you specify yourself what x and y are) but you can do it with `df.transpose()`: see [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html).

Notice in my df, country column is not an index. You can use `set_index` or `reset_index` to control it.